# Having issues deploying to gh-pages using gulp

Tags: deployment, gulp, github-pages

This is my first time asking a question on here, but I've been racking my brain on this issue and at this point, I have no idea what I'm missing or doing wrong.

I am currently trying to deploy my portfolio built with gulp to gh-pages. However, when I type "npm run gulp deploy", I get an error message that says "Cannot read property '0' of null". I'm assuming there's an error with my path for the deploy task in my gulpfile.js, but in every example I have seen for doing so "./dist/**/*" has been used with no error, so I'm not sure why my code isn't working in this case.

```
gulp.task('deploy', function () {
  return gulp.src("./dist/**/*")
     .pipe(deploy({
        remoteUrl: "https://github.com/Picke1id/idp-responsive-portfolio.git",
        branch: "master"
      }))
});
```

Thus far, I have downloaded gulp-gh-pages to my package.json, I included the deploy task in my gulpfile.js, and I created a dist folder for production (I originally had it in my .gitignore, but I tried removing it so I could add it to my repo to see if that changed anything, but it didn't).

My repo is here https://github.com/Picke1id/idp-responsive-portfolio. I will say that I am using a new css framework called CodyHouse that also utilizes gulp. Not sure if it is interfering with the deployment, but it's worth mentioning. Any help with this would be helpful and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would the error persists with the latest gulp-gh-page 0.6.0-6? (https://github.com/shinnn/gulp-gh-pages/releases)